# How to solve "Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message"?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Background:** I modified the `/examples/e2e_cli/` from [Hyperledger-fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/) and get this error message when running the end to end `script.sh`

> Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500
>   message:"make sure the chaincode mycc has been successfully
>   instantiated and try again: getccdata mychannel/mycc responded with
>   error: could not find chaincode with name 'mycc'"

The chaincode is correctly instantiated. What could actually be causing this error?

Comment: Hi @JoelEsli I am facing the same error. Did you solve it?

Comment: @user3582228: I did, the answer is below.

Answer (score -1):

This [Jira ticket](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-10913?attachmentOrder=desc) documents the problem and one thing that causes it... which does not seem directly tied to instantiation.

One cause for this error message is that the ports in the configtx.yaml are wrong or missing.

**Missing**

```
Addresses:
        - orderer0.od1.example.com
        - orderer1.od1.example.com
```

**Correct**

```
Addresses:
        - orderer0.od1.example.com:7050
        - orderer1.od1.example.com:7050
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly this file is located? Are you referring to the configtx.yaml file in config folder? Actually I couldn't file what you have mentioned :( Can  you please guide me?

Comment: Hi @JoeEsli I want to share error: Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found"