# Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to solve the following issue:

> Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found"

I have checked this answer: [How to solve "Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554362/how-to-solve-error-endorsement-failure-during-query-response-status500-mess) but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: We need more info to help you , an error message won't help us. What is the fabric version of your chaincode ? What commands did you executed before  ?  Is the chaincode correctly instantiated and approved by all orgs of the network ?

Comment: @Popopame The required information is: Version: 2.2.0
 Go version: go1.14.4
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Comment: Another problem I would like to mention is if I try [https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html#install-the-chaincode-package] so here I face some other errors while configuration. So I am facing with multiple issues at the same time. In short nothing works :(

Comment: I solved the problem in question. I am not sure will it be the actual reason or what? I update GO version and then things are working. But if I try other sections in the official tutorial [https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html#install-the-chaincode-package] I have other errors which is no annoying. As they are linked with chaincode so I post here: Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': chaincode already successfully installed